# Android phone memory

Tags: android

In my andriod phone i am getting the indication of "Insufficient memory to install and Low storage is available" in XPERIA NEO V mobile.

What does it indicate? Is there any way to increase the memory size?What do we need to see while taking the new phone?

Comment: _while taking the new phone?_?? Are you asking which phone you should buy?

Comment: Ramesh, you've been a member here for 3 years, by now you should know that this question is [wildly offline for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: You should buy a different phone.

Answer (score 2):

This indicates, that your /data partition, where all your apps are installed is almost full.

Try to uninstall unused apps. Also moving already installed apps to sdcard if possible frees memory for further installs.